# Batch-add text on images

Tags: image-processing

After a full day of searching, I can't seem to find a software that can do this for me:

I have this slightly transparent png image:

[image: I have this slightly transparent png image:]

And I want to be able to take a list of all (1000) of my articles headlines from my site, and batch add the text on this image. So that I can then have 1000 of these images all with different text on them that I can place on top of 1 background image in batch mode.

How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of putting thousands of separate images on the page (and thus slowing down its loading), why not simply use table cells or divs having the empty image as background image, and put the text on top, formatting it with CSS rules?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from batch files using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or you can do this in a completely automatic manner with [Python](https://www.python.org/) & PIL/[Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/).

In ImageMagick you can add text to just about any image and output a new image so taking the list of titles and creating a batch file from it that adds the text to the original image and outputs as a new name is quite simple, (personally I would use a python script to generate the batch file from the text list but there are many editors that can use macros to do this sort of job).

The Python + Pillow mechanism is a lot more expandable in that you could use the python some additional python libraries to actually create the list of headlines from the web site automatically and to post the images to the web site for you.

All of the above software is:

- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross platform running on Windows, Linux & OS-X at minimum.